# How to prove this inequality using am gm?

Tags: inequality

Is it true that
$$\frac{1}{3k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+3}>\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+2}$$

for all natural k? Is bashing going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS is 
$$\frac{1}{6k+2}+\frac{1}{6k+2}+\frac{1}{6k+4}+\frac{1}{6k+4}+\frac{1}{6k+6}+\frac{1}{6k+6}$$
while the RHS is
$$\frac{1}{6k+3}+\frac{1}{6k+3}+\frac{1}{6k+3}+\frac{1}{6k+6}+\frac{1}{6k+6}+\frac{1}{6k+6}$$
hence we just need to prove that:
$$\frac{1}{6k+2}+\frac{1}{6k+2}+\frac{1}{6k+4}+\frac{1}{6k+4}>\frac{1}{6k+3}+\frac{1}{6k+3}+\frac{1}{6k+3}+\frac{1}{6k+6}$$
that follows from:
$$\frac{1}{6k+2}-\frac{1}{6k+3}=\frac{1}{36k^2+30k+6},$$
$$\frac{1}{6k+4}-\frac{1}{6k+6}=\frac{2}{36k^2+60k+24},$$
$$\frac{1}{6k+3}-\frac{1}{6k+4}=\frac{1}{36k^2+42k+12},$$
$$\frac{2}{36k^2+30k+6}+\frac{2}{36k^2+60k+24}>\frac{1}{36k^2+42k+12}.\tag{3}$$
To prove $(3)$, you can use AM-GM, AM-HM or many other methods, it is not a tight inequality.

---

Another possibility is given by writing both terms as geometric series. Since:
$$\frac{1}{6(k+1)-\eta}=\frac{1}{6(k+1)}+\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\eta^j}{(6(k+1))^{j+1}}$$
and so on, we just have to prove that:
$$2\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1+2^{j}+4^j}{(6(k+1))^{j+1}}>3\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1+3^{j}}{(6(k+1))^{j+1}}$$
that is trivial since $2(1+2^j+4^j)> 3(1+3^j)$ holds by induction for any $j\geq 1$.

Comment: Nice, but doesn't use AM-GM.

Comment: @vadim123: You can use AM-GM to prove $(3)$, but it is not a tight inequality.

Comment: thanks! ill try to prove the (3)

Comment: Seems to me that it's enough to see that because k is natural, the first term of the LHS is bigger than the RHS(the denominator is smaller, the numerator is bigger), also the second term of the LHS is positive, therefore the inequality is correct

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the RHS and the LHS (line 3 in Jack d'Auruzio's answer) this way:

$\frac{1}{6k+2} \ $ (inside LHS),  is bigger than: $\frac{1}{6k+3}\ $  (inside RHS)

$\frac{1}{6k+4} > \frac{1}{6k+6}$ aswell.

We will now prove that what's left still "respects" the original (weaker) inequality:
$\frac{1}{6k+2} + \frac{1}{6k+4} > \frac{1}{6k+3} + \frac{1}{6k+3} \ \ \ \  (1)$.

We could do this very easily without using AM > GM, just do the calculations:

$\frac{(6k+4)+(6k+2)}{(6k+2)(6k+4)} > \frac{(6k+3)+(6k+3)}{(6k+3)(6k+3)}$

$ \frac{12k+6}{36k^2+36k+8} > \frac{12k+6}{36k^2+36k+9}$, which is true for any k in N.

If you want to use AM > GM you can skip my last 2 lines and observe that:

If $AM > GM$, and since $GM > HM$, then $AM > HM$ , therefore  $\frac{2}{HM} > \frac{2}{AM}$.   Consider $6k+2$ and $6k+4$, their $\frac{2}{HM}$ is just the left side of (1), while the $\frac{2}{AM} $ is just on the right side, therefore:

$\frac{2}{HM} > \frac{2}{AM}$ leads to:

$\frac{1}{6k+2} + \frac{1}{6k+4} > \frac{1}{6k+3} + \frac{1}{6k+3}$